# VARMAX Results extend causes ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, varmax

I'm trying to extend a [VARMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.html) model with new observations in order to do forward-walking validation.

However, my [`VARMAXResults.extend()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAXResults.extend.html) is throwing a `ValueError`.

Reproducible example:

```
#---- This returns: ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs ----------
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax import VARMAX
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
y_hist = 100*np.random.rand(50,2)

model = VARMAX(endog= y_hist,order=(2,0)).fit()
print("VARMAX model summary")
print(model.summary())
next_y_hat = model.forecast()
print("\nPredicted next value")
print(next_y_hat)

# simulate next observed value
next_y = next_y_hat

# extend model
model = model.extend(endog = next_y) # ValueError
```

Please note that this approach works fine in the univariate case using [SARIMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html):

```
#-------- This works fine: -------------
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

uni_model = SARIMAX(endog=y_hist[:,1],order=(2,0,0)).fit()
print("SARIMAX model summary")
print(uni_model.summary())
next_y_hat_uni = uni_model.forecast()
print("\nPredicted next value")
print(next_y_hat_uni)

# simulate next observed value
next_y_uni = next_y_hat_uni

# extend model
uni_model = uni_model.extend(endog = next_y_uni) # no ValueError
```

Versions: statsmodels v0.11.1, numpy 1.16.3.

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-347df5f5ac07> in <module>
     16 
     17 # try to update model
---> 18 model = model.extend(endog = next_y)
     19 # returns ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/varmax.py in extend(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    915 
    916         if self.smoother_results is not None:
--> 917             res = mod.smooth(self.params)
    918         else:
    919             res = mod.filter(self.params)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in smooth(self, params, transformed, includes_fixed, complex_step, cov_type, cov_kwds, return_ssm, results_class, results_wrapper_class, **kwargs)
    839         return self._wrap_results(params, result, return_ssm, cov_type,
    840                                   cov_kwds, results_class,
--> 841                                   results_wrapper_class)
    842 
    843     _loglike_param_names = ['transformed', 'includes_fixed', 'complex_step']

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in _wrap_results(self, params, result, return_raw, cov_type, cov_kwds, results_class, wrapper_class)
    736                 wrapper_class = self._res_classes['fit'][1]
    737 
--> 738             res = results_class(self, params, result, **result_kwargs)
    739             result = wrapper_class(res)
    740         return result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/varmax.py in __init__(self, model, params, filter_results, cov_type, cov_kwds, **kwargs)
    854                  cov_kwds=None, **kwargs):
    855         super(VARMAXResults, self).__init__(model, params, filter_results,
--> 856                                             cov_type, cov_kwds, **kwargs)
    857 
    858         self.specification = Bunch(**{

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in __init__(self, model, params, results, cov_type, cov_kwds, **kwargs)
   2274             'smoothed_state_disturbance_cov']
   2275         for name in extra_arrays:
-> 2276             setattr(self, name, getattr(self.filter_results, name, None))
   2277 
   2278         # Remove too-short results when memory conservation was used

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/kalman_filter.py in standardized_forecasts_error(self)
   1914                                 linalg.solve_triangular(
   1915                                     upper, self.forecasts_error[mask, t],
-> 1916                                     trans=1))
   1917                         except linalg.LinAlgError:
   1918                             self._standardized_forecasts_error[mask, t] = (

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py in solve_triangular(a, b, trans, lower, unit_diagonal, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
    334 
    335     a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
--> 336     b1 = _asarray_validated(b, check_finite=check_finite)
    337     if len(a1.shape) != 2 or a1.shape[0] != a1.shape[1]:
    338         raise ValueError('expected square matrix')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py in _asarray_validated(a, check_finite, sparse_ok, objects_ok, mask_ok, as_inexact)
    237             raise ValueError('masked arrays are not supported')
    238     toarray = np.asarray_chkfinite if check_finite else np.asarray
--> 239     a = toarray(a)
    240     if not objects_ok:
    241         if a.dtype is np.dtype('O'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in asarray_chkfinite(a, dtype, order)
    496 
    497 @array_function_dispatch(_piecewise_dispatcher)
--> 498 def piecewise(x, condlist, funclist, *args, **kw):
    499     """
    500     Evaluate a piecewise-defined function.

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Answer (score 1):

The default trend in the univariate [SARIMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) is `'n'` (for "none").  The default trend in the vector case [VARMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.html) is `'c'` (for "constant").  So, depending on what you want, do either:

1. Just set `trend='n'` if you want no trend component.  (That's actually what I wanted, but didn't realize it was not the default argument for VARMAX.) or...
2. Set `trend = 'n'` **and** use the `exog=` argument as a [workaround for a bug with the trend component in VARMAX](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6907). Thanks to `statsmodels` contributor ChadFulton, who recommended this approach until [fixed](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/6909).  His solution for when you want a constant trend:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
y_hist = 100*np.random.rand(50,2)

model = VARMAX(endog= y_hist,order=(2,0), 
               trend='n',                            # <---- notice
               exog=np.ones(y_hist.shape[0])).fit()  # <----
print("VARMAX model summary")
print(model.summary())
next_y_hat = model.forecast(exog=[1])
print("\nPredicted next value")
print(next_y_hat)

# simulate next observed value
next_y = next_y_hat

# extend model
model = model.extend(endog = next_y, exog=[1])       # <----
```